# Error with xmlhttpresponse

Tags: javascript

I have a script that in javascript that I was trying to write to read in a JSON file from an api and keep getting a 500 internal service error and I cannot for the life of me find an error anywhere in my code. I know typically a 500 internal service error is at fault of the database but I don't think it is the server, but a problem that I have in my code.

```
var pokemon = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/{1}";

pokemon.onreadystatechange = function(){
console.log(pokemon.readyState);
console.log(pokemon.status);
if(pokemon.readyState == 4 && pokemon.status == 200){
    var myArr = JSON.parse(pokemon.responseText);
    console.log("HELLO");
    myFunction(myArr);
    }
}

pokemon.open("GET", url, true);
pokemon.send();

function myFunction(arr){
    var out  = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        out += array[i].url;
        console.log(out);
    }
}
```

Here is the script that I was trying to run, and here is the documentation for the API: http://pokeapi.co/docsv2/#evolution-section

Any help would be appreciated, sorry for the long post to a probably simple problem.

Comment: A 500 is a server error, not a client side error. Either your sending it the wrong data or it's just broken

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out, I wasn't correctly using the API, thank you though! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the URL.  `{1}` is not allowed by the API.

Instead, use `var url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/1";`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't support list initialisation.

Just swap

```
var url = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/{1}";
```

for

```
var url = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/1";
```

and you should be able to catch 'em all.